# OSX: automated (every 1-2sec) screenshot (not full screen but (x,y,w,h)) using python

Tags: macos, screenshot

I want to make screenshots on OSX using python. I dont want make full screen shots but only certain rectangles on the screen. Something like (291,305,213,31). I need the correct pixel because afterwards the image files are processed by OCR (python-tesseract) to extract the text.

By the way this is since 6 years the first time I am programming, so far I only know Java a bit. I started yesterday and gave up this morning at 4am. So basically I have no clue yet...For example I still cannot build with Sublime because of path settings, but thats a different story. Cant figure out everything on one day.

I was trying already the following:
- wxPython
But the result are black images, see also:
stackoverflow.com/questions/8644908/take-screenshot-in-python-cross-platform
Additionally it only works in 32-bit mode, but when I do OCR using python-tesseract openCV requires 64-bit....

- autopy
  when trying to install I got errors, see also: 
  stackoverflow.com/questions/12993126/errors-while-installing-python-autopy
- ImageGrab
  only Windows
  effbot.org/imagingbook/imagegrab.htm
- commandline screencapture
  os.system('screencapture test.png')
  When I found this I thought, nice but only fullscreen when checking man screencapture. But then I found this: guides.macrumors.c om/screencapture
  -R capture screen rect
  That would be already enough, but on OSX 10.7.5 I dont have this option. Any ideas?
- import Quartz.CoreGraphics
  neverfear.org/blog/view/156/OS_X_Screen_capture_from_Python_PyObjC

  ## Create screenshot as CGImage

  ```
  image = CG.CGWindowListCreateImage(
      region,
      CG.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,
      CG.kCGNullWindowID,
      CG.kCGWindowImageDefault)
  ```

Unfortunately the image is not in file format but a CGImage, no idea how to save as file.

So if possible I would like to use the commandline screencapture with -R if somebody knows how. Just as a start to continue.

Are there any other command line tools available?

What about other libs that I have missed?

Cheers
M

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can get a `CGImageRef`, you can get its pixel data using the techniques described in [Technical Q&A QA1509: Getting the pixel data from a CGImage object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1509/_index.html).  In particular, it shows a function to get the pixel data as a `CFDataRef` using this function:

```
CFDataRef CopyImagePixels(CGImageRef inImage) { return CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage)); }
```

and says:

> The pixel data returned by CGDataProviderCopyData has not been color
>   matched and is in the format that the image is in, as described by the
>   various CGImageGet functions …

It shows an alternative for getting the pixel data in other formats if you need that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but to difficult for me to figure that out. I moved to windows, there are plenty of screenshot command line tools where I can specify the rectangle and it works like a charm, so I can continue with the OCR stuff.